# Define boolean type absent in ANSI C ISO/IEC-9899:1990 in Visual Studio 2012 RC

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-c++

```
typedef char bool;
```

doesn't work (Edit: it doesn't compile for "fatal error C1004: unexpected end-of-file found", not just about inference by Intellisense). Reason I assume is that bool is one of the reserved keywords in Microsoft Visual C/C++. Since I need boolean type of literal name as exact "bool" (That means, type names other than bool, such as

```
boolean
BOOLEAN
BOOL
Bool
...
```

**are not allowed**), is there a compiling option perhaps I can use to override the keyword "bool" which is **NOT** in ANSI C(ISO/IEC-9899:1990) Microsoft Visual C/C++ complies with?

NB: THIS IS NOT ABOUT C++ or VISUAL C++ AT ALL. IT'S ABOUT PROGRAMMING IN ANSI C 90 WITH MSVC COMPILER IN COMPATIBLE MODE.

Thanks in advance.

## Supplementary

Compiling option: /TC /Za

```
/* ANSI C file main.c */

typedef char bool;

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    return 0;
}
```

**(Edit: This problem has been figured out. For this case - typedef char bool - in terms of ANSI C, one can't disable Microsoft language extension by setting /Za option to work around, though Microsoft suggests the opposite. Such incoherence might be treated as a potential bug in Visual Studio 2012 RC)**

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? What message are you getting from the compiler? When one uses C compiler from the Studio, it will normally allow this `typedef` without any problems. The editor will highlight `bool` as a keyword even in C files, but that means nothing. C compiler does not treat `bool` as keyword. Did they break it somehow in VS 2012?

Comment: @Mysticial Macro works, though a new type is preferred.

Comment: @AndreyT "e:\workspace\projects\brokernet\brokernet\types.h(20): fatal error C1004: unexpected end-of-file found". Unfortunately it doesn't compile even.

Comment: @Yang: It works fine in VS2005, VS2008 and VS2010. If this error message is indeed caused by `bool` being treated as keyword by C compiler, then it must be a bug in the compiler.

Comment: I have no problem here in VS2012 RC. Could you try to set project options **Compile as C Code**?

Comment: @Yang: So, if you compile your supplementary code, which line will cause the error? (And again, just in case, what's the error message?).

Comment: @Romeo Yes I have set /TC option (Compile as C Code). After I checked options again, it turned out to compile WITHOUT /Za (Disable Microsoft language extension). That is irrational, because /Za, according to Microsoft, should be used in case of ANSI C and C++.

Comment: @AndreyT Thanks to Romeo's confirmation and I found it compiled WITHOUT /Za option which Microsoft suggests for ANSI C but actually causes this problem somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an option for the the file where you can choose what type to compile as (you can choose C or C++)

Also, have you tried stdbool.h